# Atom Editor and VS Code turn volume up all the way when opened

Tags: arch-linux, cinnamon, atom-editor, visual-studio-code

I've found that consistently VS Code or most of the time when I open Atom Editor my system audio volume suddenly turns up to 100%!

I am running Arch Linux with Cinnamon Desktop. These editors are the only two applications that do this. Other editors like Sublime text don't.

Comment: Curious, Atom and VS Code are both built on [Electron](https://electronjs.org/). Does this problem happen when you launch other Electron apps, like Slack for example?

Comment: No. Slack, the Trello desktop app, and the Electron base app don't have this problem.